# How to copy commit before merged other branch?

Tags: git

I have done a commit (`52c65fa`) with some changes that were to very linked to the branch. Then I have merged the master into the branch for solving conflicts (`544c9d9`) and then I have created a pull request. For approving the pull request, I need to remove that commit (`52c65fa`). I have thought to do another branch and move it there, but `cherry-pick` is showing an error:

```
error: could not apply 52c65fa... 
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

The graph is like this:

```
  *   544c9d9 (origin/feat/error_hierarchy, feat/error_hierarchy) Resolved conflicts
 /|   
* |   cafe7d7 (origin/dev, dev) Merged in feat/follow_photo (pull request #10)
|\ \  
| * | 2032bff (origin/feat/follow_photo, feat/follow_photo) some other branch that have been merged
|/ /  
| * 52c65fa The commit that I want to copy
| * 82e24f5 other commits
|/  
*   e534410 (HEAD, feat/config_file_review) Merged in feat/logs_work (pull request #9)
```

Where is the HEAD I want to add the commit, How shall I do it?

Comment: Why should you remove the commit for a pull request? One can simply merge with `--no-ff`, all commits will still be alive?

Comment: I want to move that commit to another branch, and have those changes

Comment: What do you see as a commit, the real files, or the `diff`?

Comment: Can you delete any uninteresting commits from your graph to simplify it? Similarly, can you tell us what commit01,02,03 belongs to which SHA-1 in your graph? Additionally, which command have you run exactly?

Comment: I have done it, sorry about that

Comment: How to move the origin of the branch to the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem: There were conflicts... I have solved them and commit again, now it is how I wanted.

Comment: Yes, that is what git told you ;).